# Displaying/geoprocessing with specific column in raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase, geoprocessing-service

I have a raster layer (let's call it `RL`) that is pulling a subset of data from a very large geodatabase. Let's say it has the following attribute table:

| OBJECTID | Value | OtherValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 | 600 |
| 1 | 300 | 700 |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 100 | 30000 | 800000 |

Ultimately, I want to run a geoprocessing routine on the OtherValue column. However, whenever I reference `RL` in any geoprocessing service, it always defaults to the `Value` field, and not the `OtherValue` field like I want it to.

How can I access other fields in the raster table in a geoprocessing service or even display it on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Lookup tool/function](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/lookup.htm):

> Creates a raster by looking up values in another field in the table of the input raster.
>
> [image]

```
outRas = Lookup("RL", "OtherValue")
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks for the suggestion!